# use two DataSource for one Repeater

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, repeater

I have two tables in the SQL server
the first:

```
ID , Journal, ScoreB 
1    aa       10.2
2    bb       3.4
3    cc       4.9
```

and the second table :

```
ID , Journal , ScoreA
1     aa       4
2     ff       3.5
4     ss       3.8
```

The two tables contain the journals and rank them in `scoreA` and `ScoreB`, some journals are in the two tables but have a different rank based on the type (`scoreA` or `ScoreB`).

I put button A and button b, when clicking A the repeater display table A and when click button b the same repeater display table B.

How can I do that? display tow table in the same repeater and also change table header (`SorceA`) to (`SourceB`) when clicked button B

UPDATE :

below the repeater code

```
   
 <asp:Repeater ID="Journals1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">

                            <ItemTemplate>
                              
    <tbody>
          <tr  class="odd views-row-first">
                         <td  class="views-field views-field-title" > <%# Eval("Journal")   %> </td> 
                         <td  class="views-field views-field-title"> <%# Eval("ScoreB")   %>  </td>
                         <td  class="views-field views-field-title"> <%# Eval("ScoreA")   %>  </td>

                     
              </tr>
        
      </tbody>
                                
 </ItemTemplate>

  
                               </asp:Repeater>
```

when the user Click buttonA the repeater display this query (SELECT * FROM JournalA
)
and when click buttonB the repeater display this query (SELECT * FROM JournalB
)
at the same repeater.
the problem in (Eval("ScoreB") ) the first query does not contain ScoreB So the repeater show error.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show the sample code

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to use a query to merge the two sets like this:

```
SELECT Journal, ScoreA,
    (SELECT scoreB from ScoreB where ScoreB.Journal = ScoreA.Journal) as ScoreB
    FROM scoreA
union all

SELECT Journal, ScoreB,
   (SELECT scoreA from scoreA where ScoreA.Journal = ScoreB.Journal) as ScoreA
   FROM ScoreB 
   WHERE not exists(select scoreA from scoreA where scoreA.Journal = ScoreB.Journal)
```

So then you only have to feed the repeater one query.

The result of the above query would thus look like this

[image]

Comment: Kindly see the update of my problem in the repeater.

Comment: Ok, but what is wrong with using the union query to merge both data sets into one query? I mean, you can always add a alias column in your two queries. I mean, either you merge the results using the above query, or you write code to merge the two results. Seems to me a whole lot easier to do this with one query as opposed to writing some merging code? but you can certainly add a alias column to query/tableA, and also add a alias column to query/TableB. And thus in both cases, the column A and B will always be returned from each query.